Support of multiple main functions in a Scala CLI script
I am trying to migrate my Ammonite Scripts to Scala CLI.
I am using lihaoyi's mainargs,like
import mainargs._
...
@main(doc = "> update ...'.")
def update(): Unit = ???

@main(doc = "> process ..'.")
def process(
             @arg(doc = "The name of the process (lowerCase, e.g. mySuperProcess).")
             processName: String,
             ...

           ): Unit = ???

Is there a way to have with Scala CLI:

multiple main functions?
documentation of the main functions and its arguments?


Scala CLI allows having multiple main classes, but you need to point which one you are using https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/commands/run/#main-class - what Ammonite does in you case is generating 1 main class, but with automatic argument parsing, and subcommands. It is not supported in Scala CLI as it does not add any automagic on top of what is already available in Scala - Scala 3 defines @main annotation but currently it only supports only a single command (see: https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/plan-for-main-and-mainargs-in-scala3/4897/21).
